# React not loading assets inside node_modules

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a react project that's unable to load any assets (png, font, etc) that resides inside dependencies installed via npm.

Font Awesome installed by `npm install font-awesome` and referred in `style.css` by `@import '~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';` is unable to load any of the font files.

Leaflet installed by `npm install leaflet` is also unable to load any image files that reside inside it's dist directory. They return a 404 error.

My `.extended-webpackrc.js` is

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {},
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {},
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```